# CocoaPods podspec platform-specific source

Tags: cocoapods, platform, podspec

Trying to set different source value for `ios` and `osx` in a podspec like so:

```
s.ios.source = {
  :http => 'https://developer.spotify.com/download/libspotify/libspotify-12.1.64-iOS-universal.zip'
  }
s.osx.source = {
  :http => 'https://developer.spotify.com/download/libspotify/libspotify-12.1.45-Darwin-universal.zip'
  }
```

But getting the error message:

> undefined method `source='

Seems like platform-specific `s.ios.source` and `s.osx.source` is not supported?

How can I specify platform-specific source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would need to create multiple podspecs. For example you could have a `spotify` and `spotify-osx`.

Comment: Alright then. Do you or anyone else know if if support for this is planned for future CocoaPods versions?

Comment: How about keeping it as one podspec and creating different targets? One iOS and one OS X target.

Comment: I haven't heard anyone mention this before. Feel free to create an issue [here](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues) to start this conversation.

Comment: @KeithSmiley is this still the case today?

Comment: Yes nothing has changed here.